# How to access an object in another class

Tags: php

Here is my class Connection in **class1.php** page

```
class Connection{
   //my other functions
   public function insert_data()
     {
         //my code
     } 
}
```

Here is my another class mydata in **class2.php** page

```
include('class1.php');
$ob=new Connection(); //first class object
class mydata
    {
       //my other functions
       $ob->insert_data();//my query passes through this insert_data()
    }
```

It returns an error : **Fatal error: Call to a member function insert_data() on a non-object in //page link** 
What is the problem in my code?
 Help me please

Comment: because you didn't initialize the related class1 in class2 .So you have to initialize class1.

Comment: The problem is you can't call `$ob` from within your class. Either pass it as an argument to set it within your function or instantiate `$ob` within your class.

Comment: How to initialize class1 in class2?

Comment: class mydata
    { public function __construct(){ $ob=new Connection(); //first class object
       //my other functions
       $ob->insert_data();//my query passes through this insert_data()}}

Comment: Sorry @Hassan ALi i try this its not work